# NestJs and GraphQL Validation Error Response

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I am using nestjs and graphql
When validation Is Failed Graphql gives Error Like These

```
 {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Field \"CreatePoolInput.clientId\" of required type \"Float!\" was not provided.",
        "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "statusCode": 500
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**and FormatError CODE**

```
        formatError: (error) => {
     // if (error.extensions.code === 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED') {
    //   // return error;

    // }
    const graphQLFormattedError = {
      //@ts-ignore
      message: error.extensions?.response?.message || error.message,
      code:
        error.extensions?.code || "SERVER_ERROR",
      name: error.extensions?.name || error.name,
      //@ts-ignore
      statusCode: error?.extensions?.response?.statusCode || 
      error?.statusCode || 500,

    };
    return graphQLFormattedError;
  },
```

**DTO Code Is**

```
import { Field, InputType } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { IsEnum, MinLength } from "class-validator";
import { PoolType, Status } from "src/pool/entities/pool.enum";

@InputType()
export class CreatePoolInput {

@Field()
orgId: number

@Field()
clientId?: Number

@IsEnum(PoolType)
@Field()
type: PoolType

@Field({ nullable: true })
name: string

@Field({ nullable: true })
description: string

@Field({ nullable: true })
list: string

@IsEnum(Status)
@Field()
status: Status;
   }
```

**But I want These Type Of Output When Validation Failed **
note: This Output is given by class-validator

```
{
"errors": [
{
  "message": [
    "clientId must be longer than or equal to 3 characters"
  ],
  "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT",
  "name": "UserInputError",
  "statusCode": 400
}
 ],
```

Give Me Solution How To modify Error Response And I am using grapql and nestjs and pgsql
I Hope you understand what is my problem